# Stage files with specific extension, and only those that show as modified in git status

Tags: git, repository

In git on the command prompt, I would like to simply add `*.cpp` and `*.h` files, but ONLY those that are showing up as modified, when I run the command `git status`.

For example, if, after I run the command `git status` I get:

Changes not staged for commit:

- modified: file1.cpp
- modified: file2.cpp
- modified: file1.h
- modified: file2.h

Untracked files:

- file3.cpp
- file3.h
- dontAddMe.blah
- dontAddMeEither.foo

Then I want to stage everything, (all the cpps and h files), except for the last two. How do I do that? Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use [`git add`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-add)'s `-u` option in conjunction with whatever other options you want:

> `-u`
> `--update`
>
> Update the index just where it already has an entry matching `<pathspec>`. This removes as well as modifies index entries to match the working tree, but adds no new files.

In this case, something like `git add -u '*.cpp' '*.h'` should do what you want.

Comment: That worked nicely. Thanks! Just as an aside, if I wanted to simply add EVERYTHING that was shown, (untracked and tracked files), what command would that be?

Comment: @TheGrapeBeyond, all tracked and untracked `.cpp` and `.h` files, or all tracked and untracked files regardless of filename?

Comment: @TheGrapeBeyond, to stage all `.cpp` and `.h` files, use the command shown in my answer without the `-u` flag. In the other case I think `git add -A` will do what you want. These were simple follow-up questions so I'm happy to help you in the comments, but in general Stack Overflow works best if you submit each new question separately.